# Percona XtraDB Cluster : Server quit without updating PID file ... server startup failed

Tags: centos, cluster-computing, xtradb

Can some one help me please ?

1) Host of my VPS (Centos) was down (Provider problem)
 
2) After VPS reboot, the node XtraDB cluster refuse to start
3) Other nodes (2) were note impacted

I read lot of posts and try to by many ways but nothing works.

i tried simple start 
i tried to remove the /var/lib/mysql/xxxxxx.com.pid and try to start
i tied to remove the lock file

always the same result :

```
#/etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster).. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/xxxxxx.com.pid).
ERROR! MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) server startup failed!
```

or

```
#/etc/init.d/mysql start
 ERROR! MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists
Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster).....State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher
.... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/xxxxxxx.com.pid).
 ERROR! MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) server startup failed!
```

or

```
#/etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep-cluster-address="gcomm://"
 ERROR! MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists
Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster).. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/xxxxx.com.pid).
 ERROR! MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) server startup failed!
```

Comment: Someone to help ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and none of the other solutions worked for me. However I had a feeling that it had something to do with running out of disk space.

What worked for me was removing the ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1 in the /var/lib/mysql directory.

The files were re-created on startup. the two logfiles were exactly the same size as previous for the ibdata1 file was half the size.

Someone may be able to confirm, but I believe the ibdata1 file met/exceeded the configured size (I did not set up this instance).

Comment: OMFG you are a life saver ! Thank you ! was banging my head so hard to figure whats wrong. briliant